# <Geolocation API> "granted" on Firefox BUT "denied" on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, permissions, geolocation, navigator

#### Greetings,

I am facing the following issue; question will follow after.

---

I have a production application using the **Geolocation API** from the navigator:

- **Yes** => the app is served over HTTPS
- **Yes** => all third-party sources are served over HTTPS
- **Yes** => I have granted geolocation on browsers

---

The results I get are:

- *localhost* => geolocation is OK on both Firefox & Chrome
- ***production*** => geolocation is **OK on Firefox**, but **not OK on Chrome**
- *Firefox* => before granting geolocation, I get the browser pop-up asking me to allow or block geolocation; **OK**
- ***Chrome*** => either before or after granting geolocation, **I get no such browser pop-up**

---

On Chrome:

- *Permissions API* => tells me that geolocation is `denied`
- *Geolocation's getCurrentPosition* => tells me that `Geolocation has been disabled in this document by permissions policy.`

---

More info:

- tech stack => *Vue3* app hosted on ***Netlify***
- production version => there are **several subdomains** according to the city selected by user
- the production app is actually for **demo purpose**; thus I cannot make any screenshot

---

#### Now, here is the question:

> What could make the whole work without any issue on Firefox, and could
> also displease Chrome?

---

Any help is highly appreciated.

#### Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem solved

I feel grateful to a wonderful colleague, whose pair of fresh eyes have permitted to look at the right place: the ***_headers*** file!

This file contained:

```
Permissions-Policy: fullscreen=(), geolocation=()
```

In the *Permissions-Policy*, you indeed write what is *permitted*, but you need to precise **what** you permit!

https://www.w3.org/TR/permissions-policy-1/#policy-controlled-feature :

> SecureCorp Inc. wants to disable use of Fullscreen and Geolocation APIs within their application. It can do so by delivering the following HTTP response header to define a permissions policy:
>
> `Permissions-Policy: fullscreen=(), geolocation=()`
>
> By specifying an empty origin list, the specified features will be disabled for all documents, including nested documents, regardless of their origin.

> SecureCorp Inc. wants to completely disable use of the Geolocation API within all browsing contexts except for its own origin and those whose origin is "https://example.com", even in the presence of an attacker who can embed their own iframes on SecureCorp’s pages. It can do this by delivering the following HTTP response header to define a restricted permissions policy for Geolocation:
>
> `Permissions-Policy: geolocation=(self "https://example.com")`

Firefox seems to ignore this however, hence the fact it was working on this browser.

Now in my *_headers* file:

```
Permissions-Policy: fullscreen=(), geolocation=(self)
Feature-Policy: geolocation 'self'
```

Cheers.